# How to parse string to update php form thru url with GET method?

Tags: php, forms, functional-programming, html-parsing

I need to parse string:

> Zakon o zaštiti na radu NN RH 59/96, 94/96, 114/03, 100/4, 86/08, 116/08, 75/09 :::: Tehnički propis za niskonaponske električne instalacije NN RH 5/10 :::: Pravilnik o sigurnosti i zdravlju pri radu s električnom energijom NN RH 88/12 :::: Pravilnik o tehn. normativima za zaštitu niskonaponskih mreža i pripadajućih trafostanica - Sl.list br. 13/78. :::: Niskonaponske električne instalacije zgrada - 6. dio: Provjeravanje - HRN HD 60364-6:2007 :::: Zakon o zaštiti od požara - NN RH 92/10 :::: Zakon o normizaciji - NN RH 55/96, 163/03

into update form. I'm using php function parseString:

```
function parseString($str) {
$result=str_replace('"','&quot;',$str);
$result=str_replace("'","&#39;",$result);
$result=str_replace("%2B","+",$result);
$result=str_replace("%20"," ",$result);
$result=str_replace("%2F","/",$result);
$result=str_replace("%28","(",$result);
$result=str_replace("%29",")",$result);
$result=str_replace("%3A",":",$result);
return $result;
}
```

But in textarea nothing is displayed

```
<tr><td width="400"><label for="primjenjeniPropisi">Opis: </label></td>
<td><textarea name="primjenjeniPropisi"><?php echo  parseString($_GET['primjenjeniPropisi']); ?></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td width="400"></td><td class="guidelines" id="guide_4"><small>Navesti naziv uredjaja, opis uredjaja i sl.</small> 
</td></tr>
```

Comment: make sure key `primjenjeniPropisi` exists in `$_GET`, by the way `str_replace` supports `array` in search and replace argumments

Comment: @bystwn22  primjenjeniPropisi exists in $_GET. This is part of code where it is defined:  echo  "<td><a href='ZP_update.php?cmd=uredi&id=". ... ."&primjenjeniPropisi=". parseString($info['primjenjeniPropisi']) ."& ...

Comment: the string you posted here (`Zakon o zaštiti na radu NN RH.....`) working fine for me, i checked, and try `htmlspecialchars` also like `<?php echo htmlspecialchars( parseString( $_GET['primjenjeniPropisi'] ) ); ?>`

Comment: @bystwn22 i tried as you suggested: htmlspecialchars( parseString( $_GET['primjenjeniPropisi'] ) ); ?> , but still nothing displayed. When i remove simbols (/:-) then it is displayed

Comment: mm.. i think the problem is with the url `ZP_update.php?cmd=uredi&id=....`.  
use `urlencode` in that link like `...&primjenjeniPropisi=".urlencode( $info['primjenjeniPropisi'] )."&...`, it will work :) good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using your custom function I recommend using `urlencode()` it should work well for you like this:

```
<?php echo urlencode($_GET['primjenjeniPropisi']); ?>
```

Explanation of `urlencode()` from PHP.net:

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It is encoded the same way that the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type. This differs from the » RFC 3986 encoding (see rawurlencode()) in that for historical reasons, spaces are encoded as plus (+) signs.

On further reflection it looks like it looks like you want to encode spaces as `%20` so you will want to use the PHP function `rawurlencode()` like this:

```
<?php echo rawurlencode($_GET['primjenjeniPropisi']); ?>
```